# Opening a page using actionscript in a custom frame

Tags: html, flash, actionscript

Is it possible to open an HTML page using navigateToURL and specifying a named frame in your HTML document? For instance, if you have an iframe on the page called "Steven", can you call

```
navigateToURL("someURL","Steven");
```

instead of something like

```
navigateToURL("someURL","_self");
```

I have tried this and it opens the URL in a new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you test this on local files saved to your hard drive? If so, then there are some security restrictions that you may be running in to. See the security note [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL()).

But if you're testing this with files on a web server, and there are no cross-domain issues, then `navigateToURL()` should work exactly the way you're using it - if your iframe's name is "Steven" then the content should be opening in that iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can use JavaScript:

```
navigateToURL("javascript:loadFrame(someURL)");
```

Then in your HTML page:

```
function loadFrame(url) {
  documents.frames[1].src=url
}
```